# Xcode "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already in use."

Tags: xcode, app-store, bundle

Xcode 8.3.  Trying to upload my app for TestFlight.  As far as I can tell, I have everything lined up: My iOS development certificate, my app ID appears to be correct, I have a distribution profile that I have downloaded and I think is installed, (although this may be a problem, when I double click on it, it opens the beta version of Xcode 9, so I'm not sure if it's really seen in my 8 version).

On Itunes Connect I created my app, it's listed as Prepare for submission, and the bundle Id is the same as what is listed in Xcode.

So what is the piece I'm missing, what's with the message?

Comment: Found it.  My app name in Xcode and in the App Store were one letter different.  That's all it was...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "app name in Xcode" and "app name in the App Store"?

Comment: Sorry, my bad for being so vague.  The Display Name in Xcode was one letter different than the name in the App Id name under Identifiers in "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles", although they have the same bundle id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think it's relevant anymore, because my app uses different names in all places, the Developer Account-AppID-Name, ITC app record app name, Xcode project name, Xcode product name, Xcode target name, Xcode bundle display name, Xcode bundle name. None is the same. My problem in the end was, I guess, that I tried to use a name reserved by Apple ("News") as bundle display name. The error message used to be better: "... uses ... name associated with an Apple app.". Now it's only "... uses ... name that's already taken".

Comment: That would do it!  I can't see how it could go through with the name being different in that many places, but the process is confusing even when it works!

Comment: I have faced similar issue. Any luck to fixed it?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it for me, just making sure that the Display Name and the App ID had exactly the same name.

Comment: I'd like to add that in Xcode 9 with this error: Changing the app name in "Product Name" under Targets > (YOUR APP) > Build Settings > Packaging works for me. Simply changing the display name or bundle display name under info.plist is superficial.